# Deduce type of reference template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

If one has a

```cpp
template <class T>
class A{};

// global namespace, static storage duration
static constexpr A<int> a;
```

is it possible to deduce the type `A<int>` by passing `a` as a reference template param such as:

```cpp
// This question asks to make the syntax in the following line compile:
static_assert(std::is_same<A<int>, typename GetReferenceType<a>::type>::value, "");
// I am aware the next line works, but it's not what I am looking for in this question
static_assert(std::is_same<A<int>, decltype(a)>::value, "");

// This is pseudo code of how this could work in theory
template <const T& RefT, class T> // I know this does not compile, but this shows what I want
struct GetReferenceType{          // which is automatically deduce type `T` without having to 
  using type = T;                 // write it out
};
```

An answer which explains why this is not possible in C++ is as welcome as a solution to make this syntax compile :)
I am mostly asking out of curiosity, since basically everything else can be deduced in templates, but apparently not reference types.

This should also work, but does not fulfill the above syntax requirement:

```cpp
template <class T>
constexpr auto GetReferenceTypeFunc(const T& t) -> T;

static_assert(std::is_same<A<int>, decltype(GetReferenceTypeFunc(a))>::value, "");
```

**Why I want to do this**

I am striving for the most concise syntax.
While `Instantiate<decltype(a)>` works, it's not ranking highly in the terseness scale, especially if a syntax like `Instantiate<a>` was possible.

Imagine `a` does not have a short type `A<int>` but instead something like
`A<OmgWhyIsThisTypeNameSoLong>`.

Then, if you want to instantiate a type with `A<OmgWhyIsThisTypeNameSoLong>`, you'd have to write:

```cpp
Instantiate<A<OmgWhyIsThisTypeNameSoLong>>;
```

It just so happens that we already have a global object `a`, so it would be nice not to have to write that long type but instead `Instantiate<a>`.

There is of course the option of creating an alias `using AOmg = A<OmgWhyIsThisTypeNameSoLong>` but I would really like to get around spamming the namespace with another very similar name to `A`.

Comment: Are you trying to use a variable name to generate a type, but without using `decltype`?

Comment: Yes kinda. I want to use the variable name as a "shorthand" for the type is has. (Imagine A<int> being really unwieldly.

Comment: I'm more curious about the actual and underlying problem you need to solve. Why do you need to do something like this? Please [edit] your question to ask about that underlying problem directly instead (otherwise it's an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)), and also please clearly state ant requirements you might have (like your "syntax requirement"). You can show us what you've tried, and tell us how it didn't work. If it's just plain curiosity then that's okay, but please tell us that.

Comment: To pass a reference to something as a template parameter, the thing you pass needs to have static storage duration. So even if you make this work it will not be very usable.

Comment: could you explain what's wrong with `Instantiate<decltype(a)>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++20, you might do:

```
template <auto V>
struct GetReferenceType
{
    using type = std::decay_t<decltype(V)>;  
};

static_assert(std::is_same<A<int>, GetReferenceType<a>::type>::value);
```

but `decltype` seems sufficient.

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/82cd3f00b3ca43fa)

> // I not only want to deduce `A<int>` but also `int`

So you probably want a trait like:

```
template <typename> struct t_parameter;

template <template <typename > class C, typename T> struct t_parameter<C<T>>
{
    using type = T;    
};
```

but simple alternative is to add info directly in `A`:

```
template <class T>
class A{
    using value_type = T;
};
```